# ASP.NET Storing Contextual Data During A Request

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, httpwebrequest

I am writing an ASP.NET application that initializes some contextual data based on stuff sent through the Request object. How should I be storing this so that it is only visible to objects dealing with the request?

Essentially I have an HttpModule that looks at the request, and does something based on the incoming data:

```
public void OnBeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e){
    if((sender as HttpApplication).Request.Url.Host == "something"){
        // Store some extra information here
    }
}
```

And then I want to retrieve the data later on in the pipeline, in a view

```
<%: somehowGetRequestSpecificData.MyProperty %>
```

How and where should I be storing that stuff?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

IMO - `HTTPContext.Items` is the best way to do this.

Ref.: https://web.archive.org/web/20201202215202/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/060904-1.aspx

HTH.

Comment: Thanks. Are there any other options?